# Missing arguments for parameters core data swiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, observedobject

I have created a list of clients which get saved in core data. I added some attributes through an AddView and now I am trying to add a new attribute using a different view. In order to do that I understood I need to use the observedObject property wrapper so that it doesn't create a new client but update the existing one. This is the code:

```
    import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct TopicView: View {
   
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
let myStudent: StudentData
@ObservedObject var topic: StudentData
@State var content = ""
@State private var show = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RadialGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.blue, .black]), center: .center, startRadius: 200, endRadius: 600)
            .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        VStack{
    
    Text("My Students")
        .bold()
        .font(.system(size: 50, design: .rounded))
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .padding(.top)
     Text("keep track of them")
        .italic()
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .font(.system(size: 25, design:.serif))

    Image(systemName: "book")
    .resizable()
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .frame(width: 80.0, height: 50.0)
        .padding(.bottom)
    }
}
                Section (header: Text("Topics covered")
                    .bold()
                    .padding(.all)
                    .font(.title3)) {
                    TextField("Add content", text: Binding(
                                get: { self.topic.content ?? ""},
                                set: { self.topic.content = $0 } )
                            )
                    //Text(topic.content ?? "")
            .padding()}
                    Button ("Save")
        { let newStudent = StudentData(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                        newStudent.content = self.topic.content
            try? self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        self.topic.content = ""
                    }.foregroundColor(.blue)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 50, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .font(.headline)
          Spacer()
                        }
```

}

I push the Topicview from a different view (StudentView), however since I added the observedObject it throws me this error in the StudentView:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99TVG.png)

I know it is something easy to fix but I could not find much information on the internet.
Thanks

Comment: Click on the little circle. Click on Fix. You should Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: I tried to add topic: StudentData as suggested by the fix notification but the error persists. I don't find anywhere the logic required there

Comment: @PaoloFarina you have to pass an *instance* of `StudentData` -- not just the type `StudentData`. For example, in the code you show above, `myStudent` and `topic` are both *instances* of `StudentData`. It's hard to give more advice than that, since your error isn't actually happening in the code that you've included in the question.

Comment: You need to pass the initial values. The View that is showing the sheet should produce and pass those as parameters/arguments. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: Hi, thanks both. I passed 'topic:myStudents' and it worked. However now it creates a new student every time I change the topic parameter from the view instead of editing the existing one from the core data. I am not sure why.